# How to open external links from my Ionic app inside a web browser view

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Step 1 : Ionic create New App. (ionic start myApp1 sidemenu)

Step 2 : Create New Page home and aboutus. (ionic generate page aboutus)

step 3 : Create button at aboutus page for url redirect to another website.

aboutus.html : (<button ion-button (click)="redirect()"> GO » <button>)

aboutus.ts : redirect() { window.open("https://www.w3schools.com/php/", "_self"); }

step 4 : When i click GO button the url redirect to w3schools.com and again browser back button click the redirect to home page only. i need redirect to aboutus page. help me any one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use it [In App Browser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) Ionic Native plugin

Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser
```

**In  app.module.ts add InAppBrowser Provider**

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

providers: [
  InAppBrowser,
]
```

Html:

```
 <ion-buttons>
    <button ion-button (click)="redirect()"> GO » <button>
 <ion-buttons>
```

In ts:

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';


 constructor(private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser) {}

redirect() {
 this.inAppBrowser.create("https://www.w3schools.com/php/");
}
```

you can also see this [**video tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPJ9TdHaI3A)

Comment: I saw your video. That is based on cordova plugin.I am Ionic 3 PWA Developer. i will not access cordova plugin. my requirement is ionic PWA link to website and return to PWA for browser(firefox or chrome). have you any idea?

Comment: Try it so `window.open("https://www.w3schools.com/php/",'_system', 'location=yes');`

Comment: Working fine but website is open popup. is it correct way?

Comment: if you wont open browser view in yours app use InAppBrowser Plugin, I have no other idea

Comment: Thanks for reply.