# Redirect link in Ionic text field not opening in browser

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an app containing multiple editable forms.

In all of them there is a URL field. I want this to open that URL in a browser window. Unfortunately at present it opens with my sites URL prepended before it.

ie If someone enters www.othersite.com and my site URL is www.mysite.com, clicking on the link will open www.mysite.com/www.othersite.com

How do I get the app to open www.othersite.com instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285051/how-to-open-external-links-from-my-ionic-app-inside-a-web-browser-view/50286332#50286332 See this

Comment: I have tried that, however I have to append 'https://' to the link. This is fine if a user only enters www.othersite.com, however it would be preffered if Ionic would not assume that missing http at the front of the URL means to add the apps URL to the front.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

Add Cordova Inappbrowser plugin and try

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://www.othersite.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

or

```
window.open('www.othersite.com','_system','location=no');
```

Comment: The first one did not work, and the second one opened in a popup which I did not want to happen.